# How to call array out from Java method

Tags: java

I created an array *Pages* in method *List*. 
Could you please advise how to call out one element Pages[1] when accessing method List() from other classes?

```
public List() {
String[] Pages = { 
"www.cnn.com",
"www.bbc.com",
"www.yahoo.com",
};
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You can only use it within metod, move it outside if you like to reference it.

Comment: variables and methods in Java are usually lowercase, classes and interfaces are usually uppercase. Also not good to reuse names in the standard classes, e.g. `List`

Comment: That doesn't look like a method, as it doesn't have a return type. It looks like a constructor. Perhaps a review of [Java basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) is in order.

Comment: By the way `String[] pages={"www.cnn.com","www.bbc.com","www.yahoo.com"};`, you don't end every element in the array definition with ';' and there mustn't be any comma after the last element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a `local`variable from a method directly. You must return it somehow.

Btw, it looks like you don't understand really well how methods work in Java. You should check [it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Here's an example of what do you want to do:

```
public String[] listPages(){

     String [] pages = {"www.cnn.com", "www.bbc.com", "www.yahoo.com"};

     return pages;
}
```

Later if you want to use one of the elements of the `array`, you should do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     String[] res = listPages();
     //now we want to print the element one: www.cnn.com

     System.out.println(res[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you xFunkyTImes, it helped me to move on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class named `List` and a constructor for that class.
Also there are redundant `;,` between the elements of the array.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It should be a comment.